# Калькулятор при нажатии на кнопки возвращает Nan

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Вот код:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      firstNum: null,
      secondNum: null,
      operand: '',
      number: [
        {
          id: 'one',
          num: '1',
        },
        {
          id: 'two',
          num: '2',
        },
      ]
    }
    
    this.handleNum = this.handleNum.bind(this);
    this.handleClearData = this.handleClearData.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleNum(event){
    this.state.number.forEach(
      i => {
        if(event.target.id == i.id){
          console.log(i.id)
          this.setState(
            {
              firstNum: parseInt(`${this.state.firstNum}` + i.num)
            }
          )
        } 
      }
    )
    
    console.log(this.state.firstNum)
  }
  
  handleClearData(){
    this.setState(
    {
      firstNum: null,
      secondNum: null,
      operand: '',
    }
    )
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
      <>
        
        <div id = 'number'>
          <div className = 'container px-4 text-center overflow-hidden'>
            <div className = 'row row-cols-3 g-5'>
              <div className = 'col-12'><div id = 'display'>
                { this.state.firstNum ? `${this.state.firstNum + this.state.operand}` : '0' } { this.state.secondNum ? `${this.state.secondNum}` : '' }
              </div></div><br/><br/>
              
              <div className = 'col'><div id="one" className = 'number' onClick = {this.handleNum}>1</div></div>
              <div className = 'col'><div id="two" className = 'number' onClick = {this.handleNum}>2</div></div>
              <div className = 'col'><div id="three" className = 'number' onClick = {this.handleNum}>3</div></div>

              <div className = 'col'><div id="four" className = 'number col' onClick = {this.handleNum}>4</div></div>
              <div className = 'col'><div id="five" className = 'number col' onClick = {this.handleNum}>5</div></div>
              <div className = 'col'><div id="six" className = 'number col' onClick = {this.handleNum}>6</div></div>

              <div className = 'col'><div id="seven" className = 'number col'>7</div></div>
              <div className = 'col'><div id="eight" className = 'number col'>8</div></div>
              <div className = 'col'><div id="nine" className = 'number col'>9</div></div>

              <div className = 'col'></div><div class = 'col justify-content-center'><div id="zero" class = 'number'>0</div></div>
              <div className = 'col'><div id="decimal" className = 'col number'>.</div></div>
              
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <br/>
          
          <div className = 'container px-4 text-center overflow-hidden'>
            <div className = 'row row-cols-3 g-5'>
              <div className = 'col'><div id = "equals" className = 'number col'>=</div></div>
              <div className = 'col'><div id = 'subtract' className = 'number'>-</div></div>
              
              <div className = 'col'><div id = 'add' className = 'number'>+</div></div>
              <div className = 'col'><div id = 'clear' className = 'number' onClick = {this.handleClearData}>CD</div></div>
              <div className = 'col'><div id = 'divide' className = 'number'>/</div></div>
              <div className = 'col'><div id = 'multiply' className = 'number'>*</div></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

В массиве this.state.number находятся цифры и их id в объектах. При нажатии на кнопки срабатывает handleNum, который проходится по списку, и добавляет число в this.state.firstNum с типом string, а после конвертируется в int, но после изменений this.state.firstNum становится Nan. Я пробовал убрать кнопки, цифр которых нет в массиве, но это не помогло решить проблему

Comment: Если `NaN` - значит один из операндов "не число"... Проверяй все свои вычисления и смотри что с чем у тебя вычисляется...